# Adding IEEE copyright notice to LaTeX template

Tags: formatting, templates, ieeetran, ieeeconf, copyright

I am trying to add the IEEE copyright notice to the template provided here: http://www.icb2019.org/Misc/icb2019_latex_for_review.zip

I have tried the following commands:

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-5386-5541-2/18/\$31.00~\copyright2018 IEEE \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}
```

I am relatively new to LaTeX. It appears this is because the document class is 'article' not 'IEEEtran'. However, when I change this to IEEEtran it ruins the formatting of the rest of the paper.

How can I add the copyright notice without ruining the default formatting of the template?

I am aware of similar questions to this, however, they address the default IEEE template. My issue here is that the template (above) is not the IEEE template and therefore cannot use the same commands.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If you are preparing this manuscript to submit to IEEE for publication, they will expect you to use their template.  I can't say with assurance that they *will* change it, but having worked for another publisher for many years, I can verify that some publishers *do* do this.  So it's much better if you do it on your own -- that way you will have control.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hello. Thank you. I am using the template linked above, as required. However, there appears to be no way to add the requested copyright notice.

Comment: Every publisher I know about will add their copyright notice once they have your file and are preparing it for publication.  So you shouldn't need to worry about it, especially if that is the only thing that makes the template "unsuitable".  (It would probably a good idea for publishers to say that in their instructions.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am seeking to add the copyright notice myself to this template because this particular conference requires I add it. Could you help me amend the template I have linked to such that I can do this? This is common for some conferences, e.g.: http://sites.ieee.org/compel2018/ieee-copyright-notice/

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, use IEEE Latex Template. Now do the following

Add the following code **before** the `\maketitle` command**:

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-5386-5541-2/18/\$31.00~\copyright2018 IEEE \hfill}
\hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}
```

Add the following code **after** the `\maketitle` command:

```
\IEEEpubidadjcol
```